# Dynamics CRM upsert request with related entities error

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, upsert

I am using MS Dynamics CRM 2016 On-Premises.

I am loading data through OrganizationService, using Upsert request.

[image: screenshot]

And I am getting an error:

> Entity Id must be specified for Update

As I understood - related Campaign ([0] in RelatedEntities on screen) record does not exist and should be created during upsert, and wave record should be updated.
But there isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you populating the Alternate Keys for that record? The record must have either an .Id or .KeyAttributes.

From your screenshot the .Id is an empty Guid but not sure about the .KeyAttributes field.

Comment: Hi, Jordi.
Thank you for your answer.
The record with empty Id should be created, shouldn't it?
It dosn't exist in database yet. How the alternate keys will help to update record which is not created yet?

I thought about two different requests for that entities, but they should go in a single transaction, and I have no ideas how to set the relationship with entity, which is not created yet, in other way.

With regards, Yuriy.

Comment: Should be created as long as you set an alternate key value... because you need at least one or the other.

Comment: @YuriyD  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932135(v=crm.7).aspx) are more details

Comment: The main objective is, what I am trying to do - to load into CRM some linked records in single transaction, using ExecuteTransactionRequest. Some of records could be new and some of them could already be created in CRM.

Comment: From [section Understanding the Upsert Process section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn932135.aspx), the upsert needs to be called with enough data (.Id or AlternateKeys). This is because, it needs to check if it has to create or update the record. So even for create, it is expecting the alternate keys so that the next time it is called, it will know it will have to update the record, rather than creating it. It needs to do a lookup first, basically.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jordi.
It didnt work for me when I set the entity with key attributes as related entity,but it works with the relations should be set as 
new EntityReference("entity", "key_attr_name",key_attr_value).
I used separate query for each entity with references in single transaction.